# Script to backup SQL Server and save the files into Amazon s3

Tags: sql-server, bash, amazon-s3, powershell-3.0

I'm trying to set up an automatic backup from SQL Server to S3 script or batch, but I didn't find the way who to do it without a third party software.. :(

Any of you have an experience before with it?

Thanks in advance,

Bernat

Comment: Is the backup file just a normal .bak file?

Comment: I would create a SQLAgent job to call Ola Hallengren's DatabaseBackup stored procedure, then add a PowerShell job step using the Write-S3Object cmdlet to send the backups to a S3 bucket

Comment: @TTeeple, just the normal .bak.

Comment: @supergrady, thanks, I'm going to try it. I never used it before.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I found a workaround, maybe is not the best way to do it, but i don't need to keep the files in EC2 server volume and i can move it to s3.
I create a normal backup job, keeping the files for two days and synchronizing the local folder to S3 with AWS command cli job every morning. With this we are moving every day the files to S3 folder:

```
aws s3 sync folder s3://mybucket1
```

I hope that it helps.

Cheers,

Bernat